# Using advanced captions with bxslider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sharepoint-2010, bxslider

I'm using bxslider to rotate some images - they take up 50% of the container. I want to use the other half for a caption div, containing multiple block elements (for title, subtitle, date, description).

By default, bxslider calls captions through the title attribute, which would be perfect if I weren't needing to use multiple elements as part of the caption.

Does anyone know of a working example that's similar to what I'm looking for? Or, even better, how could the bxslider configuration be modified to meet my specifications?

Comment: you can append your own element using `onSliderLoad()` callback

Comment: can you submit your code here or on jsfiddle, that way we can get more clear picture of what you need.

Comment: Here's a JS fiddle which contains easier to read HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/astewes/Bp4Uw/

Answer (score 5):

You can simply add a `<div>` inside the `<li>` of bxslider and
inside that div you can create whatever layout you want.

I've created an example for you here : [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phoenix4rmhell/Bm52B/)

I hope this solves your problem